# VueJS $watch $refs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is it possible to `$watch` Vue `$refs`?

I'm wanting to set logic against a child component that is nested inside my current Vue instance but inside the `ready` callback, `$refs.childcomponent` is initially `undefined` while it's processed.

**inside `ready()`**

```
this.$watch('$refs', function() {
    console.log("not firing");
}, { deep: true });
```

Result: Error: Maximum call stack exceeded

**`watch` property of the instance**

```
watch: {
  '$refs': {
     handler: function() { console.log("hit"); },
     deep: true
  }
}
```

result: nothing.

Comment: Is `;` here `deep: true;`  is by typo ?

Comment: Yes, that isn't in the actual code, thats just my bad port over to stackoverflow. Good spot, removed.

Comment: `deep: true` => Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43651090/cant-access-data-variables-in-watch-handler-vuejs

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can `$watch` `$refs.<name>.<data>` but not `$refs.<name>` itself, not to mention `$refs`.

https://jsfiddle.net/kenberkeley/9pn1uqam/

```js
const Counter = {
  data: () => ({
    i: 0
  }),
  template: `<fieldset>
    <p>Counter</p>
    <code>i = {{ i }}</code>
    <button @click="i += 1"> Add One </button>
  </fieldset>`
}

const App = {
  components: { Counter },
  mounted () {
    this.$watch(
        () => {
            return this.$refs.counter.i
        },
      (val) => {
        alert('App $watch $refs.counter.i: ' + val)
      }
    )
  },
  template: `<fieldset>
    <p>App</p>
    <counter ref="counter" />
  </fieldset>`
}

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    render: h => h(App)
})
```

Comment: $refs.<name> may be undefined when mounted. you should `this.$watch(() => this.$refs.comp.prop, (val) => {...})` when comp is created.

Comment: @aztack So do it in `mounted` hook

Comment: @KenBerkeley not necessarily, an element with a ref can be created at anytime. For example, an element representing an article can be created after an API call has return a response, on a button click.

Comment: How is this the excepted answer? OP says: `$refs.childcomponent is initially undefined while it's processed.` I am in the same situation and template looks like: `<div v-if="product"><div ref="myRef">` so in mount `this.$refs.myRef` is undefined and `this.$refs.myRef.someProp` will throw. Googling for `vue watch ref` get me this answer at the top but I can't see how this answer can work for me or the OP

Comment: The way I solved it is to watch `product`: `watch: { product() { this.$refs.myRef` because `v-if` conditionally renders the ref if product is truthy.

Comment: Funny.  I came here to +1 and had already done so.  Ergo, great solution!

Answer (score 36):

No, `$refs` are not reactive, watch won't work.

Comment: Yup...   ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: So what is the proper Vue way to react to DOM elements changes?

Comment: There appears to be two ways to "watch" in Vue.  You can create functions within the `watch` block of a component, or call `this.$watch` which _will make $refs reactive_ so to speak.

Answer (score 4):

In mounted use code below:

```
this.$watch(
        () => {
            return this.$refs.<name>.<data>
        },
      (val) => {
        alert('$watch $refs.<name>.<data>: ' + val)
      }
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a work around to this. Consider that JavaScript doesn't create a copy of an array when assigning it to a variable, it merely creates a reference to the original array. Knowing that Vue's $refs are arrays, we can do the following:

```
<template>
    <div>
            <ul v-if="showAvailable">
                 <li v-for="pet in allPets.available" :key="pet.id" ref="pets">
                      {{ pet.name }}
                 </li>
            </ul>
            <ul v-else>
                 <li v-for="pet in allPets.unavailable" :key="pet.id" ref="pets">
                      {{ pet.name }}
                 </li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    props: ['allPets'],

    data() {
         showAvailable: true // Normally would change from a button or something
         shownPets: null // set to null for now
    },

    mounted() {
         this.$set(this.$data, 'shownPets', this.$refs.pets);    
    },

    watch: {
         shownPets: {
                         handler(newVal, oldVal){
                              // Do something when the DOM changes!
                         },
                         deep: true
                    }
    }
}
</script>
```

And voilà. We set our data `shownPets` to our pets `$ref` after the component mounts. The reference will hold different elements based on if `showAvailable` is `true` or `false`, and now we can watch for $ref or DOM changes.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible if you define the property in $refs during created(), or during beforeCreate() if you don't need the backing store in data. For example:

```js
const vm = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
        mode: 0,
        refTest: undefined
    };
  },
  created() {
    Object.defineProperty(this.$refs, 'test', {
      get: function () {
        return this.refTest;
      }.bind(this),
      set: function (newValue) {
        console.log(`set - Setting test refs to an array? ${Array.isArray(newValue)}`);
        this.refTest = newValue;
      }.bind(this),
      enumerable: true
    });
  },
  watch: {
    refTest: {
      handler(newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log(`watch - array? ${newValue ? Array.isArray(newValue) : undefined}`);
      },
      deep: false,
      immediate: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle() {
        this.mode = (this.mode === 1) ? 2 : 1
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="toggle">Toggle</button>
  <ul v-if="mode === 1">
    <li ref="test">Single Ref</li>
  </ul>
  <ul v-else-if="mode === 2">
    <li ref="test" v-for="s in ['Multiple', 'Refs']" :key="s">{{ s }}</li>
  </ul>
  <div v-else>No Refs</div>
</div>
```

This is the only solution I have experimented with which works when the ref is not mounted along with the component itself.

The reason to use defineProperty here is because if the ref changes, the watcher will lose track of it.

If you want to handle your action right in the defineProperty, I suppose that would be ok and then you could get rid of your watcher. But you will always need to have a backing store -- though it doesn't need to be in data.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked in my case, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the following solution uses [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/MutationObserver)

in mounted hook add :

```
const config = {
      attributes: true,
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    };
 // this will be triggered for any change in your element
    this.observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
      mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
        if (mutation) {
          this.infoHeight = this.$refs.info.clientHeight + 'px'
          console.log(" changed ", this.$refs.info.clientHeight)
        }
      });
    });
//observe the referenced element
    this.observer.observe(this.$refs.info, config);
```

**Full example**

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    infoHeight: 0,
    observer: null,

    img: "https://images.ctfassets.net/hrltx12pl8hq/6TOyJZTDnuutGpSMYcFlfZ/4dfab047c1d94bbefb0f9325c54e08a2/01-nature_668593321.jpg?fit=fill&w=480&h=270"

  }),
  mounted() {
    const config = {
      attributes: true,
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    };
    this.observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
      mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
        if (mutation) {
          this.infoHeight = this.$refs.info.clientHeight + 'px'
          console.log(" changed ", this.$refs.info.clientHeight)
        }
      });
    });
    this.observer.observe(this.$refs.info, config);


  },

 beforeDestroy(){
   this.observer.disconnect()
  },
  methods: {
    changeImg() {
      this.img = "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a7/3d/6e/a73d6e4ac85c6a822841e449b24c78e1.jpg"
    },

  }
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app" class="container">
  <p>{{infoHeight}}</p>

  <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="changeImg">Change image</button>
  <div ref="info">
    <img :src="img" alt="image" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested in Vue 3: you can at least use a shallow `$watch` on `$refs` in `mounted()`

```js
mounted () {
  this.$watch(
    '$refs',
    this.$refs.childComponent?.whatever(),
    { immediate: true }
  )
}
```

Using the optional chaining operator (`?.`) is important as `$refs.childComponent` may be undefined initially. But when it is added to `$refs`, the watcher will be triggered again.