# Vue.js deep watch scope issue?

Tags: vue.js, scope, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to implement a form that looks up existing locations, it's pretty much a simple search.

The problem is that none of the properties inside the watcher are updated. I can see that `this.locations` is changed when the API responded, same for `this.searchInProgress`, but the view of the component doesn't update.

```
import locations from '../../api/Locations';
import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect';

export default {
    name: 'LocationWidget',

    components: {
        Multiselect
    },

    watch: {
        formData: {
            deep: true,
            handler: (newValue, oldValue) => {
                this.searchInProgress = true;
                console.log(this.searchInProgress);
                locations.search(newValue).then((result) => {
                    this.locations = result.data.locations;
                    //this.searchInProgress = false;
                    console.log(this.locations);
                }).catch((e) => {
                    //this.searchInProgress = false;
                });
            }
        }
    },

    data() {
        return {
            searchInProgress: false,
            locations: [],
            formData: {
                location: '',
                street: '',
                street2: '',
                city: '',
                zip: '',
                country_id: null,
            }
        }
    },
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you defined the watch handler with an arrow function, which means `this` inside this function is *not* the component, but the global scope.

Solution: Use a normal function.

```
handler(newValue) {
```

Comment: After this explanation it's obvious... I hate the scope issues in JS. :( Is there any best practice to debug this kind of issue? Also this question can be closed as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43651090/cant-access-data-variables-in-watch-handler-vuejs, just found that a moment ago.

Comment: When using an arrow function is used with a closure, is the scope always going to be the global scope or just the scope of the object one level above?

Comment: It's always set to the scope that you're in at the moment of defining the function. in the context of your example, that would be the global scope (or `undefined` in strict mode)