# VueJS / JS DOM Watch / Observer in a multi phase render scenario

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**Scenario:**

I’m developing a Vue scroll component that wraps around a dynamic number of HTML sections and then dynamically builds out vertical page navigation allowing the user to scroll or jump to page locations onScroll.

**Detail:**

**a.**  In my example my scroll component wraps 3 sections. All section id’s start with  `"js-page-section-{{index}}"`

**b.**  The objective is to get the list of section nodes (above) and then dynamically build out vertical page (nav) navigation based on the n number of nodes found in the query matching selector criteria. Therefore, three sections will result in three page section navigation items. All side navigation start with  `“js-side-nav-{{index}}>".`

**c.**  Once the side navigation is rendered I need to query all the navigation nodes in order to control classes, heights, display, opacity, etc. i.e  `document.querySelectorAll('*[id^="js-side-nav"]');`

**EDIT**

Based on some research here are the options for my problem. Again my problem being 3 phase DOM state management i.e. STEP 1. Read all nodes equal to x, then STEP 2. Build Side Nav scroll based on n number of nodes in document, and then STEP 3. Read all nav nodes to sync with scroll of document nodes:

1. Create some sort of event system is `$emit() && $on`. In my opinion this gets messy very quickly and feels like a poor solution.  I found myself quickly jumping to $root
2. `Vuex`.  but that feels like an overkill
3. `sync`.  Works but really that is for parent child property state management but that again requires `$emit() && $on`.
4. `Promise`.  based service class. This seems like the right solution, but frankly it became a bit of pain managing multiple promises.
5. I attempted to use Vue $ref but frankly it seems better for managing state rather than multi stage DOM manipulation where a observer event approach is better.
6. The solution that seems to work is Vues `$nextTick()`.  which seems to be similar to AngularJS `$digest`. In essence it is a `. setTimeout()`.  type approach just pausing for next digest cycle. That said there is the scenario where the tick doesn’t sync the time requires so I built a throttle method. Below is the code update for what is worth.

The refactored watch with nextTick()

```
        watch: {
            'page.sections':  {
                handler(nodeList, oldNodeList){
                    if (this.isNodeList(nodeList) && _.size(nodeList) && this.sideNavActive) {
                        return this.$nextTick(this.sideNavInit);
                    }
                },
                deep: true
            },
        },
```

**The REFACTORED Vue component**

```
<template>
    <div v-scroll="handleScroll">
        <nav class="nav__wrapper" id="navbar-example">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li role="presentation"
                    :id="sideNavPrefix + '-' + (index + 1)"
                    v-for="(item, key,index) in page.sections">
                    <a :href="'#' + getAttribute(item,'id')">
                    <p class="nav__counter" v-text="('0' + (index + 1))"></p>
                        <h3 class="nav__title" v-text="getAttribute(item,'data-title')"></h3>
                        <p class="nav__body" v-text="getAttribute(item,'data-body')"></p>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import ScrollPageService from '../services/ScrollPageService.js';

    const _S = "section", _N = "sidenavs";

    export default {
        name: "ScrollSection",
        props: {
            nodeId: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            sideNavActive: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: true,
                required: false
            },
            sideNavPrefix: {
                type: String,
                default: "js-side-nav",
                required: false
            },
            sideNavClass: {
                type: String,
                default: "active",
                required: false
            },
            sectionClass: {
                type: String,
                default: "inview",
                required: false
            }
        },
        directives: {
            scroll: {
                inserted: function (el, binding, vnode) {
                    let f = function(evt) {
                        if (binding.value(evt, el)) {
                            window.removeEventListener('scroll', f);
                        }
                    };
                    window.addEventListener('scroll', f);
                }
            },
        },
        data: function () {
            return {
                scrollService: {},
                page: {
                    sections: {},
                    sidenavs: {}
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            getAttribute: function(element, key) {
                return element.getAttribute(key);
            },
            updateViewPort: function() {
                if (this.scrollService.isInCurrent(window.scrollY)) return;

                [this.page.sections, this.page.sidenavs] = this.scrollService.updateNodeList(window.scrollY);

            },
            handleScroll: function(evt, el) {
                if ( !(this.isScrollInstance()) ) {
                    return this.$nextTick(this.inViewportInit);
                }

                this.updateViewPort();
            },
            getNodeList: function(key) {
                this.page[key] = this.scrollService.getNodeList(key);
            },
            isScrollInstance: function() {
                return this.scrollService instanceof ScrollPageService;
            },
            sideNavInit: function() {
                if (this.isScrollInstance() && this.scrollService.navInit(this.sideNavPrefix, this.sideNavClass)) this.getNodeList(_N);
            },
            inViewportInit: function() {
                if (!(this.isScrollInstance()) && ((this.scrollService = new ScrollPageService(this.nodeId, this.sectionClass)) instanceof ScrollPageService)) this.getNodeList(_S);
            },
            isNodeList: function(nodes) {
                return NodeList.prototype.isPrototypeOf(nodes);
            },
        },
        watch: {
            'page.sections':  {
                handler(nodeList, oldNodeList){
                    if (this.isNodeList(nodeList) && _.size(nodeList) && this.sideNavActive) {
                        return this.$nextTick(this.sideNavInit);
                    }
                },
                deep: true
            },
        },
        mounted() {
            return this.$nextTick(this.inViewportInit);
        },
    }

</script>
```

**END EDIT**

---

**ORIGINAL POST**

**Problem & Question:**

**PROBLEM:**

The query of sections and render of navs work fine. However, querying the nav elements fails as the DOM has not completed the render. Therefore, I’m forced to use a  `setTimeout()` function. Even if I use a watch I’m still forced to use timeout.

**QUESTION:**

Is there a promise or observer in Vue or JS I can use to check to see when the DOM has finished rendering the nav elements so that I can then read them? Example in AngularJS we might use $observe

**HTML EXAMPLE**

```
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
            <scroll-section>
                <div id="js-page-section-1"
                     data-title="One"
                     data-body="One Body">
                </div>
                <div id="js-page-section-2"
                     data-title="Two"
                     data-body="Two Body">
                </div>
                <div id="js-page-section-3"
                     data-title="Three"
                     data-body="THree Body">
                </div>
            </scroll-section>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**Vue Compenent**

```
<template>
    <div v-scroll="handleScroll">
        <nav class="nav__wrapper" id="navbar-example">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li role="presentation"
                    :id="[idOfSideNav(key)]"
                    v-for="(item, key,index) in page.sections.items">
                        <a :href="getId(item)">
                        <p class="nav__counter">{{key}}</p>
                            <h3 class="nav__title" v-text="item.getAttribute('data-title')"></h3>
                            <p class="nav__body" v-text="item.getAttribute('data-body')"></p>
                        </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <slot></slot>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "ScrollSection",

        directives: {
            scroll: {
                inserted: function (el, binding, vnode) {
                    let f = function(evt) {
                        _.forEach(vnode.context.page.sections.items, function (elem,k) {
                            if (window.scrollY >= elem.offsetTop && window.scrollY <= (elem.offsetTop + elem.offsetHeight)) {
                                if (!vnode.context.page.sections.items[k].classList.contains("in-viewport") ) {
                                    vnode.context.page.sections.items[k].classList.add("in-viewport");
                                }
                                if (!vnode.context.page.sidenavs.items[k].classList.contains("active") ) {
                                    vnode.context.page.sidenavs.items[k].classList.add("active");
                                }
                            } else {
                                if (elem.classList.contains("in-viewport") ) {
                                    elem.classList.remove("in-viewport");
                                }
                                vnode.context.page.sidenavs.items[k].classList.remove("active");
                            }
                        });

                        if (binding.value(evt, el)) {
                            window.removeEventListener('scroll', f);
                        }
                    };

                    window.addEventListener('scroll', f);
                },
            },

        },
        data: function () {
            return {
                page: {
                    sections: {},
                    sidenavs: {}
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            handleScroll: function(evt, el) {
                // Remove for brevity
            },
            idOfSideNav: function(key) {
                return "js-side-nav-" + (key+1);
            },
            classOfSideNav: function(key) {
                if (key==="0") {return "active"}
            },
            elementsOfSideNav:function() {
                this.page.sidenavs = document.querySelectorAll('*[id^="js-side-nav"]');
            },
            elementsOfSections:function() {
                this.page.sections = document.querySelectorAll('*[id^="page-section"]');
            },

        },
        watch: {
            'page.sections': function (val) {
                if (_.has(val,'items') && _.size(val.items)) {
                    var self = this;
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        self.elementsOfSideNavs();
                    }, 300);
                }
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.elementsOfSections();
        },

    }


</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide simple codepen (or similar) example for this? Why is `:id="[idOfSideNav(key)]"`, you don't need `[]` around id. Also, you could skip `classList.contains("in-viewport")`, and just use `classList.add("in-viewport")`. [From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Methods): __add() Adds the specified class values. If these classes already exist in the element's class attribute they are ignored__ same for remove

Comment: have you tried using refs and watch for that possibly? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39035498/vuejs-watch-refs

Comment: @ljubadr thanks. The solution that worked is posted above. It seems $nextTick() was the solution.

Comment: @Gowri thanks. I could not get $ref to work properly. It seems like an child parent workable solution, but doesn't seem to work well with multi stage or phase DOM manipulation

Answer (score 0):

I hope I can help you with what I'm going to post here. A friend of mine developed a function that we use in several places, and reading your question reminded me of it.

> "Is there a promise or **observer** in Vue or JS I can use **to check** to see **when** the DOM has finished rendering the nav elements so that I can then read them?"

**I thought about this function ([source](https://github.com/Markkop/codeSnippets/blob/f78cf3fcbe60786dfae91b856b67c5fd43ba7ce9/waitForExistence.js)), here below. It takes a function (observe) and tries to satisfy it a number of times.**

I believe you can use it at some point in component creation or page initialization; I admit that I didn't understand your scenario very well. However, some points of your question immediately made me think about this functionality. *"...wait for something to happen and then make something else happen."*

<> **Credits to [@Markkop](https://github.com/markkop) the creator of that snippet/func  =)**

```js
/**
 * Waits for object existence using a function to retrieve its value.
 *
 * @param { function() : T } getValueFunction
 * @param { number } [maxTries=10] - Number of tries before the error catch.
 * @param { number } [timeInterval=200] - Time interval between the requests in milis.
 * @returns { Promise.<T> } Promise of the checked value.
 */
export function waitForExistence(getValueFunction, maxTries = 10, timeInterval = 200) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let tries = 0
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      tries += 1
      const value = getValueFunction()
      if (value) {
        clearInterval(interval)
        return resolve(value)
      }

      if (tries >= maxTries) {
        clearInterval(interval)
        return reject(new Error(`Could not find any value using ${tries} tentatives`))
      }
    }, timeInterval)
  })
}
```

#### Example

```js
function getPotatoElement () {
  return window.document.querySelector('#potato-scroller')
}

function hasPotatoElement () {
  return Boolean(getPotatoElement())
}

// when something load
window.document.addEventListener('load', async () => {
  // we try sometimes to check if our element exists
  const has = await waitForExistence(hasPotatoElement)
  if (has) {
    // and if it exists, we do this
    doThingThatNeedPotato()
  }

  // or you could use a promise chain
  waitForExistence(hasPotatoElement)
    .then(returnFromWaitedFunction => { /* hasPotatoElement */
       if (has) {
         doThingThatNeedPotato(getPotatoElement())
       }
    }) 
})
```